# Unix: How can I search for a word that appears in a column in a csv

Tags: unix, grep, cygwin

I have a csv data set with two columns that looks like this

```
Andrew, hello I'm from Germany
Andy,   I'm from Cambodia
Arthur, I come from Hong Kong
Alec,   I'm of african descent
Richard,I'm chinese
Tess,   I'm Tess, i also come from Cambodia
```

If I wanted to search the second column of this csv for the keyword 'cambodia' and return something that looks like

```
Andy,   I'm from Cambodia
Tess,   I'm Tess, i also come from Cambodia
```

I've tried $ cut -d ',' -f1,2 file | grep -i "\bcambodia\b"
However this code also searches the first column, which I do not want, I only want to search the second column, and I want to keep the first column in the output

Comment: Use `csvgrep` from the `csvkit` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider `awk` using the comma as a delimiter

```
$ awk -F, '/Cambodia/ && $1 !~ /Cambodia/' input_file
Andy,   I'm from Cambodia
Tess,   I'm Tess, i also come from Cambodia
```

By using `,` delimiter, you can exclude column 1 matching the string `$1 !~ /Cambodia/` while matching every other column that will contain the string